# Check string for Steam Game Key

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, steam

basically I need help with checking if a certain string contains a certain pattern:

Here are a few strings in an array:

```
[ "please use this key: ')D9ad-98ada-jiada-8a8aa'",
  "kK8AD-AODK8-ADA7A",
  "heres a free game for you guys dkaa2-21ddd-9a9aa-9wada"
]
```

I need to check the entire array, for keys, that follow this key format from Steam:

```
Please keep the real keys formats, as told by steam and seen bellow:
AAAAA-BBBBB-CCCCC
AAAAA-BBBBB-CCCCC-DDDDD-EEEEE
```

I know I would need a for loop like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<arrayName.length;i++) {
    // What should be in here?
}
```

What should be //In there? To check the strings in the array for that certain Key Pattern.

also, please keep in mind that I first need to remove the text, and then check the key.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: That seems to be a homework question, and you don't tell us what you tried. How can you find a text pattern? Are Regex allowed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure i've used regex before but I've used it way too little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you a solution without Regex. You'll have to find by yourself a solution with Regex as a homework

```js
var data = [ "please use this key: ')D9ad-98ada-jiada-8a8aa'",
  "kK8AD-AODK8-ADA7A",
  "heres a free game for you guys dkaa2-21ddd-9a9aa-9wada"
];
var result = [];
data.forEach(x => {
  var flag = true;
  var array = x.split("-");
  if (array.length === 3 || array.length === 5){
    array.forEach(y => {
      if (y.length !== 5) flag = false;
    });
  }
  else flag = false;
  if (flag === true) result.push(x);
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out and see how it goes

Comment: I've tried it out and tried to modify it a bit. It seems to only be taking the data arrays that ONLY include the steam keys. It dosen't remove the text, then takes the key..

Comment: Ok but a question remains : what is the rule to recognize a key in the midst of string? is a key bordered by simple quotes .... ?

Comment: See that's the thing, the Key is bordered by nothing an is merely randomly put in, in a string.

Comment: So you will have to extract the key with a Regex

Comment: I knew that I would have to use Regex, but I just did not know how to get it to work. How can I search in the entire string for something matching a pattern, the program that checked it up there